# org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Mapping qname not fond for the package: org.joda.time.chrono

Tags: java, hibernate, web-services, apache-axis, jodatime

I use Hibernate as ORM for my webservice.

I get following error, when I try to access data through the web service.

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Mapping qname not fond for the package: org.joda.time.chrono
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Mapping qname not fond for the package: org.joda.time.chrono
    at org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.BeanUtil.getPropertyQnameList(BeanUtil.java:264)
    at org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.BeanUtil.getPropertyQnameList(BeanUtil.java:117)
    at org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.BeanUtil.getPropertyQnameList(BeanUtil.java:117)
    at org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.BeanUtil.getPullParser(BeanUtil.java:72)
    at org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.reader.ADBXMLStreamReaderImpl.processProperties(ADBXMLStreamReaderImpl.java:993)
    at org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.reader.ADBXMLStreamReaderImpl.next(ADBXMLStreamReaderImpl.java:850)
    at org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.reader.ADBXMLStreamReaderImpl.next(ADBXMLStreamReaderImpl.java:853)
    at org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.reader.ADBXMLStreamReaderImpl.next(ADBXMLStreamReaderImpl.java:853)
    at org.apache.axis2.util.StreamWrapper.next(StreamWrapper.java:71)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:651)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:189)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMContainerHelper.build(OMContainerHelper.java:150)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.build(OMElementImpl.java:695)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.detach(OMElementImpl.java:674)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMContainerHelper.addChild(OMContainerHelper.java:117)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.addChild(OMElementImpl.java:225)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPBodyImpl.addChild(SOAPBodyImpl.java:195)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.addChild(OMElementImpl.java:221)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.processResponseAsDocLitWrapped(RPCUtil.java:441)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:159)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:114)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.service(AxisServlet.java)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.__invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1527)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1484)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Mapping qname not fond for the package: org.joda.time.chrono
    at org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.BeanUtil.getPropertyQnameList(BeanUtil.java:131)
    ... 50 more
Oct 05, 2015 4:20:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [AuthenticateController] in context with path [/Webservice_client] threw exception
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Mapping qname not fond for the package: org.joda.time.chrono
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:375)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:421)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
    at ws.AuthenticateStub.getAppSettingsForUserEmail(AuthenticateStub.java:1117)
    at com.ips.tvawsclient.authenticate.AuthClient.getAppSettingsByUserEmail(AuthClient.java:87)
    at controller.AuthenticateController.doGet(AuthenticateController.java:60)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.__invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1527)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1484)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

It seems, ADB doesn't support Joda time. Do I need to convert all the Joda time to Java date time? Is there any other solution because I don't want to convert it to Java data time.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a DTO to expose a class or collection.
For example.

**Method webservice**

```
public UserDTO getUserById(int idUser) throws Exception {
    UserDTO resultado = null;
    try {
        UserDAO usuDAO = new UserDAO();
        resultado = new Mapper().Map(usuDAO.getUser(idUser));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }

    return resultado;
}
```

**Method Mapper**

```
public class Mapper implements IMapper {
    @Override
    public UserDTO Map(User User) {
        return new UserDTO(User.getIdUser(), User.getUser(), User.getPassword(), User.getName());
    }
}
```